# can't get stderr value from a subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, pipe

I have code

`proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)`
`stdout, stderr = proc.communicate()`

I tried invalid commands assigning to cmd, but stderr always is Null

An invalid command like 'ls fds' returns 'ls: cannot access fds: No such file or directory'
But the message doesn't appear in neither stdout nor stderr.

Comment: That error message is thrown by your shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works fine for me:

```
$ python
Python 2.5.1 (r251:54863, May  5 2011, 18:37:34) 
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5465)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import subprocess
>>> cmd = ['ls', 'fds']
>>> proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE) 
>>> stdout, stderr = proc.communicate()
>>> stdout
''
>>> stderr
'ls: fds: No such file or directory\n'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might be confusing stderr and the process's return code (available in `proc.returncode` after you've called `proc.communicate()`). stderr is the second output stream available to the process. It's generally used for printing error messages that shouldn't be mixed with the process's normal ("standard") output, but there's no rule that says it MUST be used for that purpose, or indeed that it MUST be used at all. And if you pass invalid commands to the `cmd` argument of `Popen()`, then stderr will never be used since no command actually gets run. If you're trying to get the error code (a numeric value) from the process, then `proc.returncode` is what you want.